Hasse principle for Brauer groups of fields of transcendence degree 2
In his paper "A Hasse principle for function fields over PAC fields" (DOI link), Ido Efrat proves the following result: Let $F$ be an extension of a perfect PAC field $K$ of relative transcendence degree 1. Then the restriction map
$$\operatorname{Res}: \text{Br}(F) \rightarrow \prod_{v \in \mathbb{P}(F/K)} \text{Br}(F_v^h)$$ is injective, where $\mathbb{P}(F/K)$ denotes the set of non-trivial valuations on $F$ that are trivial on $K$, and $F_v^h$ denotes the henselization of $F$ with respect to $v$. I was wondering if there are analogue statements for the Brauer groups of fields $F$, where $F/K$ is of relative transcendence degree 2?

Every infinite subfield of the algebraic closure of a finite field is a perfect PAC field.  So you are looking for statements that work for these fields.  Efrat’s theorem is analogous to the reciprocity exact sequence in class field theory.  I know no similar result in transcendence degree 2.

Do you know of any other results in transcendence degree 2? It doesn't have to involve PAC fields at all, I am mainly interested to learn which such fields have a Hasse principle for Brauer groups.
